# Tengo un problema con redimensionamientos de fuentes y botones en diferentes dispositivos Android

Tags: windows-forms, xamarin, xamarin.android

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Soy muy nuevo en Xamarin Forms y me he encontrado con un problema aparente muy desagradable con la estética final del producto. He estado usando emuladores como Genymotion y Android Studio pero me encuentro que la estética frontal del programa no corresponde de ningún modo en el Emulador en comparación con un móvil y un segundo móvil. No termino de comprender por qué en cada sistema se ve de una manera diferente al resto: frases cortadas, botones más largos o cortos, botones fuera de pantalla, menú lateral desplazable desaparecido... y la verdad es bastante frustrante llegar a entender que en cada móvil con pulgadas y resolución diferente se van a ver de manera distinta.

Seguramente estoy haciendo algo mal y por ello agradecería un empujón en la dirección correcta, puesto que Xamarin es muy nuevo para mí y carece de un editor gráfico, tal y como dispone Windows Forms en Visual Studio por ejemplo.

No entiendo por qué en un móvil Xiaomi Redmi Note 9S o Mi A3 no se ven ni siquiera ninguna letra en este código que viene tras un menú lateral desplazable de opciones.

```
<RefreshView x:DataType="local:ItemsViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
<CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        SelectionMode="None">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Padding="10,10" x:DataType="model:Item">
                <Label Text="{Binding Opcion}"
                    LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                    Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                    FontSize="16" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Informacion}" 
                    LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                    Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                    FontSize="13" />
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer 
                        NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                        Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ItemsViewModel}}, Path=ItemTapped}"     
                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                    </TapGestureRecognizer>
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

y tampoco entiendo por qué en esta zona se ve diferente en ambos dispositivos hasta el punto de que no cuadran las frases y se quedan partidas. ¿Tiene algo que ver la resolución de cada aparato? ¿Cómo se consigue que se vea igual en cualquier dispositivo? Además, en este segundo caso el Grid 1, que deriva de un primer Grid 0, curiosamente sufre algo tan extraño como que si deslizas el scroll demasiado hacia arriba desaparece el texto del Grid 1 y no hay manera de devolverlo salvo yendo hacia atrás en el menú y regresando a la ventana donde está este Grid 1. Es como si se perdiera tras el Grid 0.

```
    <Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<ScrollView Grid.Row="1">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Label Text="Loops" TextColor="OrangeRed" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="40" FontAttributes="Bold" Padding="0,20,0,20" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        <Label x:Name="und_" Text="Amount" BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="LightBlue" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="25" Padding="5,6,7,0" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Gracias a todos.